SQL query to identify rows in a table that fall within a specific range of rows
I have a table with six columns ordered by date and time (Items, Type, Date, Time, TypeID, Value). I want to identify rows in this table with a SQL query that fall between a row where TypeID is 102 and the Value is 1, and another row where TypeID is 102 and the Value is 0.
Here is a sample data, the row that I want to identify are highlighted in yellow:


I tried recursive statements and partitioning in sql but not successful.

Please check this link on how to ask a good SQL question. Also show us what you tried and what is not working in it. Also mentioned the RDBMS and Version you are using like Oracle or MySQL

see: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Also instead of saying "I tried ..." show the code you tried (but not as an image).

You just need to use window functions to conditionally count the marker rows, then check that the count of starter markers is exactly one more than end markers.
WITH counted AS (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 102 AND Value = 1 THEN 1 END)
        OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS T102V1,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID = 102 AND Value = 0 THEN 1 END)
        OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS T102V0
    FROM YourTable t
)
SELECT *
FROM counted
WHERE T102V1 - 1 = T102V0
  AND TypeID <> 102;


Thanks @Charlieface, this solved the problem.
